# make snod didn't work, with waring like this:No rule to make target 'out/target/product/generic/root/file_contexts', needed by 'snod'

Tags: android, gnu-make, android-source

Every time I typed `make snod`,this happened:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'out/target/product/generic/root/file_contexts', needed by 'snod'.  Stop.`

Truth is, I didn't have a directory named root in `/out/target/product/generic` at all. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make snod` is used to build the system image from the current software binaries. It is used when you change some libraries in android sources and don't want to rebuild whole system, then you build incremental changes in that library (using `mm`) and do `make snod` to include those changes in system image. 
Maybe you didn't build android image for first time?
You also need to source 
(`source build/envsetup.sh`) script in shell and `lunch` build configuration.